# Example of a continuous $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with $[\text{Jac}(f)(\vec{a})]\vec{v} = D_{\vec{v}}f(\vec{a})$ but not differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous and all directional derivatives $D_{\vec{v}}f(\vec{a})$ exist at the point $\vec{a}$, and let $[\text{Jac}(f)(\vec{a})]$ denote the Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ at $\vec{a}$.

If you can find a vector $\vec{v}$ such that $[\text{Jac}(f)(\vec{a})]\vec{v} \neq D_{\vec{v}}f(\vec{a})$, then you know that $f$ is not differentiable at $\vec{a}$, since the derivative at a point $\vec{a}$ sends vectors to directional derivatives at $\vec{a}$. However, what if no such vector exists? Can you conclude that $f$ is differentiable?

There are many examples of functions $f$ which are continuous and for which all directional derivatives exist, but are not differentiable. However, what if you assume also that $[\text{Jac}(f)(\vec{a})]\vec{v} = D_{\vec{v}}f(\vec{a})$ for all $\vec{v}$? Does this additional assumption change anything?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} x \qquad y=x^2 \\ 0 \qquad \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
Then it is not too difficult to check that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and  $$D_vf(0)=0=\text{Jac}(f)(0)v$$ for any $v\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$.  However, if we assume $f$ is differentiable then we should have $$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{|f(v)-f(0)-\text{Jac}(f)(0)v|}{|v|}=0.$$  We get a contradiction by approaching $x=0$ along the curve $y=x^2$.